# Objective C: Error in creating uibuttons from array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I am stuck at this following codes:

```
btn1 = [UIButton alloc];
btn2 = [UIButton alloc];
btn3 = [UIButton alloc];
btn4 = [UIButton alloc];
btn5 = [UIButton alloc];
btn6 = [UIButton alloc];
NSArray *myarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6,nil];

for (int i =0; i < [myarray count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"What: %@", [myarray objectAtIndex:i]); // Result UIButton
    [myarray objectAtIndex:i].frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);// error, cant build
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)[myarray objectAtIndex:i];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);
    [b setTitle:@"my button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    b.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    b.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    b.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x93/255.0 green:0x73/255.0 blue:0x47/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    b.tag = i+1;
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview: b];
    [b release];
}
```

Originally I use switch case, like:

```
switch (i)
    case 0: {
        /*
        ..... 
        repeat this code
        .....
    }
```

Thus if use switch case, the codes are very long. The reason I loop it is:

- The position
- Try not to repeat the code, like set the title, background, add target etc

Or do you have a simpler/shorter code?

Comment: How different could the buttons be on each run - if only a few different choices can't you use Xcode / Interface Builder to build the GUI - then a few adjustments in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have alloced the UIButtons but have not initialized them.

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

You also need to cache the UIButton pointer in the loop

```
UIButton *currentButton = [myarray objectAtIndex:i];
```

then replace all instances of '[myarray objectAtIndex:i]' with 'currentButton'

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1 = [UIButton alloc];
```

You need to init after alloc otherwise you have just allocated garbage memory

```
btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

Also

```
[myarray objectAtIndex:i].frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);// error, cant build
```

fails because it does not know what class the object is and therefore if it can call setFrame: on it, which is why you need to cast it as a button (which is a UIView subclass)

```
UIButton *b = (UIButton *)[myarray objectAtIndex:i];
b.frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this?

```
for (int i =0; i < [myarray count]; i++)
{
    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100)];
    [b setTitle:@"my button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    b.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    b.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    b.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x93/255.0 green:0x73/255.0 blue:0x47/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    b.tag = i+1;
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview: b];
    [b release];
}
```

I think you forgot to initialize your buttons. There are different ways to initialize them. init, initWithFrame and initWithCoder

Answer (score 0):

```
[myarray objectAtIndex:i].frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);// error, cant build
```

Is giving you an error because you can't use dot syntax to access cast (or in this case, `id`) objects. If you remove this line and put the following after you have set `b`:

```
b.frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);
```

You will no longer get the error.

You could also optimise your loop using fast enumeration:

```
for (UIButton *b in myArray)
```

The other answerers are correct in pointing out that you aren't creating the buttons properly in the first place - use `buttonWithType` or `alloc` and `initWithFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIButton *btn3 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIButton *btn4 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIButton *btn5 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIButton *btn6 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    NSArray *myarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6,nil];

    for (int i =0; i < [myarray count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"What: %@", [myarray objectAtIndex:i]);        
        UIButton *b = (UIButton *)[myarray objectAtIndex:i];
        b.frame = CGRectMake(i* 110+25, 60, 100, 100);
        [b setTitle:@"my button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        b.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        b.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        float red = 0.33;
        float green = 0.82;
        float blue = 0.48;

        //Color values are float values between 0 and 1;

        b.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
        b.tag = i+1;
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self.view addSubview: b];
        [b release];
    }
```